# bypass root in system app

Tags: java, android, shell, root

Hi i am working on app called ota updater from custom roms like cm , los and aosp but problem is aosp has not got root by default and ota updater needs root permission to run commands like

```
                Shell.SU.run("mount -o rw,remount,rw /cache";
```

but it's not possible for users to do in roms like aosp is there any way to by pass root (run without root but grant permission to write cache) and my app is system app 
here is app 
https://github.com/Grace5921/OtaUpdater

and here is file in which i want to add that

https://github.com/Grace5921/OtaUpdater/blob/master/app/src/main/java/io/github/otaupdater/otaupdater/activity/OpenScriptGenerator.java

Thanks for any help